# having difficulty with average sub query

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns in a table for Players in a sport:

name, performance (good or bad), salary (integer)

I am now trying to first only get the list of all players that are good.

Then I want the average salary of all the good players.

I have tried various options and now stuck here:

```
Select AVG(salary) "Average Salary of good player"
(
  Select salary
  where performance = 'good');
FROM  Players
```

I am fairly new to sql and trying to practice, please help.

Thanks

Comment: There is a fixed sequence of "clauses" in a sql select query. Don't even think about changing that sequence. || select || from || where || group by || having || order by || while you don't have to use them all, do use them in that sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT AVG(salary)             -- select average salary on entire table
FROM Players
WHERE performance = 'good';    -- but only for players with good performance
```